# R install 2.15.2 Renvirons not found, Ubuntu 12.10 x64

Tags: r, installation, package, ubuntu-12.10

Ubuntu 12.10 x64, R 2.15.2

I'm at a loss, I've installed R numerous times and never had the slightest problem with the install. This time however when I launch the program (either by using the GUI or by typing "R" in the terminal) I get this;

> cannot find system Renviron Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace()
>   for 'utils', details:   call: options(op.utils[toset])   error:
>   invalid value for 'editor'
>
> R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) -- "Trick or Treat" Copyright (C) 2012
>   The R Foundation for Statistical Computing ISBN 3-900051-07-0
>   Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>
> R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. You are
>   welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions. Type 'license()'
>   or 'licence()' for distribution details.
>
> Natural language support but running in an English locale
>
> R is a collaborative project with many contributors. Type
>   'contributors()' for more information and 'citation()' on how to cite
>   R or R packages in publications.
>
> Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
>   'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help. Type 'q()' to
>   quit R.
>
> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:
>   call: options(op.utils[toset])   error: invalid value for 'editor' In
>   addition: Warning message: package "methods" in
>   options("defaultPackages") was not found  Error : .onLoad failed in
>   loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:   call: options(op.utils[toset])
>   error: invalid value for 'editor' In addition: Warning message:
>   package ‘utils’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found  Error :
>   .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'utils', details:   call:
>   options(op.utils[toset])   error: invalid value for 'editor' In
>   addition: Warning message: package ‘stats’ in
>   options("defaultPackages") was not found  During startup - Warning
>   message: package ‘methods’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found

Nothing works, no packages are found. I've never received any training on how to use Ubuntu, but from what I can gather I am missing the recommended packages for R.

I've tried completely removing R using both the Terminal as well as Synaptics Package Manager, then re-downloading the from CRAN servers (it seems to download too fast for my internet connection) and then reinstall. Same message. I'm at a loss.

Comment: How are you installing R? What GUI are you referring to? Have you followed the instructions at http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html?

Comment: as per the instructions on the CRAN website I added the repository for Quantal with the local mirror [link](http://probability.ca/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu) and then ran `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install r-base` I'm thinking maybe some dependencies are missing?

Comment: Try uninstalling R, then `sudo rm -r /etc/R/` then re-install R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and setting the EDITOR environment variable solved the problem for me.

Try e.g.

```
EDITOR=vim R
```

If that works, put the line

```
export EDITOR=vim
```

at the end of your ~/.profile

**EDIT:** the root of the problem was that /etc/R/Renviron was not read by R. As Dirk commented on his reply,

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/R/Renviron
```

solves the problem

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. That is fixed in the newest Debian R packages which should propagate to CRAN as Ubuntu ports in due course too.

Comment: Thank you very much Tomas, That worked like a charm! I was starting to worry that I would need to reinstall Ubuntu or go back to Windows on my home computer!

Comment: @AlaskaKraska You need better debugging skills. When a single package breaks, you do not need to leave an OS. If a single version of a package fails, it can help to look at what changes were made. That would have led you to /etc/R/Renviron which I was asked to create differently -- hence the (accidentally) wrong mode.

Comment: Great. Worked for me.

Comment: The first part of this solution (before the EDIT) worked for me with debian KDE in kate. R was starting fine from konsole but not from the Terminal embedded into kate. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be the following :

```
error: invalid value for 'editor'
```

You can try to type the following in a terminal to know what the value of your `EDITOR` environment variable currently is :

```
echo $EDITOR
```

And maybe you should be able to start R from the command-line with something like :

```
EDITOR="" R
```

Comment: `echo $EDITOR` doesn't print out anything in the terminal. Should I be typing anything else before? or should I be in the R directory?

Comment: If it doesn't print out anything, it should be because the variable is not set. But then it shouldn't be the problem that prevents R to start. I presume that `EDITOR="" R` doesn't work either ?

Answer (score 1):

But it starts to get dicy before it gets to `editor` -- it seems like it fails to load your saved environment.   Can you try

```
 R --no-restore-data
```

or even

```
 R --vanilla
```

Needless to say, it works for me and the only configuration change made was in the Java stack (see the Changelog file).

There is a dedicated list `r-sig-debian` for the Debian and Ubuntu packages where you'd get me (Debian packages), Johannes (Debian backports, available via CRAN) and Michael (Ubuntu builds, available via CRAN).  I tend to run Michael's packages on my Ubuntu machines and have not had an issue.

Comment: Both  `R --no-restore-data` and  `R --vanilla` produce the same results as before. I've tried removing R and reinstalling it, but it doesn't do anything either. I'm at a loss for what to do.

Comment: It may be http://bugs.debian.org/701774 which I just fixed: try `sudo chmod 644 /etc/R/Renviron`.  Otherwise: dunno. Works on all my Ubuntu machines.

Comment: I'm not sure if it was you or Tomas who answered first with the `sudo chmod 644 /etc/R/Renviron` fix, but it worked, so Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problems after I insall R and RStudio too.Both of them apear to have problems same as yours.
I can't find the .Renviron in /etc/R.Then I search the Internet and find out I should use this file to set envirenments for my R. So all I need to do is new a ".Renviron" file and write it correctly. 
Fortunatelly I find a file named "Renviron.site" in /etc/R and inside it I find a few lines of comments :

```
   # ## Example .Renviron on Windows
   # R_LIBS=C:/R/library
   # MY_TCLTK="c:/Program Files/Tcl/bin"……
```

I suppose this would be useful to write my .Renviron file. 
So I write these in terminal:

`sudo gedit /etc/R/.Renviron`
The .Renviron file is automatically created and open by gedit.Later on I copy

`R_LIBS=~/R/library`

`PAGER=/usr/local/bin/less`

`R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES='utils,grDevices,graphics,stats'`

into .Renviron file and save it.And the RStudio just work normally!